# MOSS query the SiteUserInfoList list

Tags: sharepoint, moss, list, caml

I want to know how I can connect to the SiteUserInfoList using U2U CAML Builder tool, I know I can do it in code. But want to be able to quickly query it through the tool so I can bring back the values it holds.

**Or a better question... where is the SiteUserInfoList information held in the content database (mysites or site content database?)**

...I looked in Alllists table and filtered by tp_Title column, but no rows were returned....

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good article that explains how this information is stored in Sharepoint.

SiteUserInfo gets stored in content database and the userprofile data in the SSP database.

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-7-MOSS_User_Profile_Info_-_How_the_information_flows.aspx